# sleep indefinitely

Tags: c, sleep

I was wondering if there is a statement which I can use to have a program sleep indefinitely (probably using sleep function??). (I am obviously doing this waiting for a signal that is going to be delivered at some time to this process and it will wake it up)

Comment: I don't think there's anything like that in the C language.  It would be OS-dependent (I've run pre-standard C on systems that didn't have a sleep capability built in), so you should let us know what OS.  I'd suspect something in the Unix family from your mention of a signal, but I could bd wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but I recommend you mark aschepler's answer correct as `pause()` has problems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<strike>You want [pause()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pause.html).</strike>

**EDIT:** The most likely circumstances under which you might want to use `pause()` [will actually cause a race condition](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Pause-Problems.html#Pause-Problems), so prefer [`sigsuspend()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/sigsuspend.html).

Comment: Don't use `pause`. It has an inherent race condition whereby the signal you're waiting for might be delivered just before the pause. `sigprocmask` and `sigsuspend` are the right way to handle it.

Comment: R.: Good point.  A nice explanation here: http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Pause-Problems.html and on the following page.

Answer (score 4):

On Unix, see either [`pause`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pause) or [`sigsuspend`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigsuspend).

Answer (score 1):

And on Windows use [Sleep(INFINITE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686298.aspx)

Comment: That should be Sleep(INFINITE)